# JavaScript COM port close after write and read

Tags: javascript, com-port

I am trying to read data from a hardware.

The procedure should be as follows:

1. send bookmarks to the hardware

```
await writer.write(encoder.encode("X"));
```

2. the device gets the bookmark and now knows that it has to send data back. I let the buffer overflow and wait 1 second for all data to arrive. In addition, the data is sent to the background software via AJAX.

```
setTimeout(async function () {
...
}, 1000);
```

In the next step I want to close the COM port so that the user can read out again if necessary. The simplest thing would be to close the port and just call the same method.

But I don't know how to do that. Actually, after a successful data transfer, my programme should be saved in the

```
if (done){
}
```

loop. But this does not happen. At least console.log is not listed.

Code:

```
if ("serial" in navigator) {
    hardwareData = '';
    readData();


    async function readData() {
        console.log('read');

        //Prompt the user to select any serial port.
        const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
        // Waits until the serial interface is open. + hardware Parameter.
        await port.open({ baudRate: 115200, dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1, parity: "none" });

        //Send "X" to hardware
        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
        await writer.write(encoder.encode("X"));
        writer.releaseLock();


        //Wait 1 second and read Port
        setTimeout(async function () {
            
            // Port read
            while (port.readable) {
                const reader = port.readable.getReader();

                try {
                    while (true) {
                        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
                        if (done) {
                            //  Allow the serial interface to be closed.
                            reader.releaseLock();
                            console.log('test');
                            break;
                        }
                        if (value) {
                            //console.log(value);


                            hardwareData = hardwareData + new TextDecoder().decode(value);
                            hardwareData = hardwareData.replace(/\s/g, '');

                            var res = et2Daten.split(";");

                            var anzahl = res.length;


                            if (anzahl == 173 || anzahl == 169) {
                                console.log("Anzahl: " + anzahl);
                                //console.log(et2Daten);

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: APPLICATION_PATH + 'Home/ReadDataFromET2',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: JSON.stringify({
                                        'data': et2Daten,
                                    }),
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        console.log(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function (request) {
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to close my port most effectively?

Comment: Can't help with the answer but at least variables can't be named with dash: "hardware-data" is an incorrect variable name.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just changed it so that it makes sense. In my code, this is written together, of course.